# Trigger using old, new table, inserting into two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm new at creating Triggers in SQL and trying to get this one working (using Mysql). It's supposed to take the new (update) version of a blog entry and put it into the table called EditedPosts, and just leave the original row in the table Posts unchanged.

I've tried a few different ways but cannot get it to work. Anybody have any ideas?

My trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER editedPost 
BEFORE UPDATE on Posts
for each row
begin
insert into editedPosts VALUES (PostID, Titel, Content, Created, UserName, BlogID) FROM new;
insert into Posts VALUES (PostID, Titel, Content, Created, UserName, BlogID) FROM old;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

My table Posts:

```
create table Posts (PostID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT not null,
                          Titel VARCHAR (50) not null,
                          Content TEXT not null,
                          Created timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp,
                          UserName VARCHAR (50) not null,
                          BlogID INTEGER not null,
                          primary key (PostID),
                          foreign key(UserName) references User_Accounts(UserName),
                          foreign key (BlogID) REFERENCES Blogs (BlogID));
```

My table EditedPosts:

```
create table EditedPosts (EPostID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT not null,
                          PostID INTEGER not null,
                          Titel VARCHAR (50) not null,
                          Content TEXT not null,
                          Created timestamp,
                          Edited timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp,
                          UserName VARCHAR (50) not null,
                          BlogID INTEGER not null,
                          primary key (EPostID),
                          foreign key (PostID) REFERENCES Posts(PostID),
                          foreign key(UserName) references User_Accounts(UserName),
                          foreign key (BlogID) REFERENCES Blogs (BlogID));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is more commonly done as an after `update` trigger.  But that doesn't really make a difference.

In any case, you don't need to update the row in Posts at all.  Then you need to fix your insert into `EditedPosts`:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER trg_post_update
BEFORE UPDATE on Posts
for each row
begin
    insert into editedPosts (PostID, Titld, Content, Created, UserName, BlogId)
        VALUES (new.PostID, new.Title, new.Content, new.Created, new.UserName, new.BlogID);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Actually, if you want to keep the original values . . . rather than updating them.

I don't think MySQL has an `instead of` trigger.  And I don't think there is a way to prevent the update without generating an error.  That leaves reassigning the values:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER trg_post_update
BEFORE UPDATE on Posts
for each row
begin
    insert into editedPosts (PostID, Titld, Content, Created, UserName, BlogId)
        VALUES (new.PostID, new.Title, new.Content, new.Created, new.UserName, new.BlogID);

    set new.PostID = old.PostId,
        new.Title = old.Title,
        new.Content = old.Content,
        new.Created = old.Created,
        new.UserName = old.UserName,
        new.BlogID = old.BlogID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

For this, you really do want a `before update` trigger.

Comment: Tanks for your input. As you say, there is no instead of trigger in Mysql, so I've been using before. If I reassign the values as you show in you second trigger, won't that move the old values to the EditedPosts instead of keeping them in the original Posts table? I want the new (edited) input to be stored in the EditedPosts.

Comment: Would it maybe be easier to create a trigger to collect certain kind of data from the Posts table and make the edit be created in the "Edited Posts" table from the beginning?

Comment: @SoX . . . No, it won't do that.  The new values go into `editedPosts` *before* they are changed.

Comment: Thanks so much, finally got it working! You're a star!